# How can I change CPU multiplier or CPU base Clock in real?

Tags: cpu, frequency, motherboard

I have i7 950 with X58_T3H6(motherboard) and I tried to increase my clock.as you can see, I change my CPU multiplier in BIOS and set it to x21, but in throttle stop, u can see that my cpu freq is 12*133MHZ. as you can see that, my CPU multiplier wasn't change!!!its stuck in x12!
also, i could change my cpu base clock(now its 133MHZ), but i cant change my cpu multiplier in real!
its just change in bios, but in real, it doesn't change after all.
i really need your Hint :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1v5g.png)

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is intended for programming questions. Try posting your question in https://superuser.com/, which is for general computer software/hardware questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Enable SpeedStep and press the Turn On button. You also need to enable the core C states in the BIOS, at least C3, if you want your CPU to use the maximum turbo boost multipliers.